# Applying to PhD programs in mathematics, how to address (now resolved) health issues that affected GPA and subject GRE scores?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, gre, gpa, health

I want to apply to a doctoral program in mathematics (I am currently a master's student) that is strong in algebra. The schools I found that have what I am interested in are "tier 1" schools with very competitive admissions and I am not sure what to do to improve my application. I had to withdraw a semester after my first year of graduate school because of several health problems, and when I went to the doctor I was told I had severe iron deficiency anemia as well as another medical issue I do not want to discuss here. I had it for almost ten years, but my previous doctor never diagnosed it. My GPA has suffered a lot from its side effects (it is 3.3) and also my subject GRE from undergrad is terrible (560). I was not able to retake the subject GRE because of a time conflict.

I want to apply for Fall 2016 because my health is a lot better now, but I am not sure what to do to make my application better. I feel like if I try to explain my health issue it will look like I am trying to make excuses. I have done seminar presentations, gone to an algebra conference, and done independent work without a faculty adviser (they always seem to tell me they are too busy or that I should stop studying material outside of classwork).

If someone can offer a suggestion on how I should approach explaining my situation or could suggest something for me to do to make myself more competitive, it would really help.

Comment: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly) addresses the general question of how to overcome poor GPA/GRE scores, but I'm hoping someone will answer in more detail whether to address health issues in your application, and how.  (The answer to the "general" question hints at addressing this in the SOP, but doesn't give much detail.)